# ResourceNotFound when launching [robot]_moveit_config launch_file

Tags: moveit, ros-hydro, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

This is a test I created for a customized robot, say DENSO vp6242, which is not available in the original ROS package. This package I create is vp6242_config (according to tutorial, this should be vp6242_moveit_config) with some configurations and Moveit Setup Assistant packge

I'm not certain about how to register this customized package but I used .bashrc and double checked with roscd, rospack find and both recognized vp6242_config package.

However, when I run

```
roslaunch moveit_planning_execution.launch
```

the error is returned

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 279, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 257, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 206, in _start_infrastructure
    self._load_config()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 121, in _load_config
    self.config = roslaunch.config.load_config_default(self.roslaunch_files, self.port, verbose=self.verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 428, in load_config_default
    loader.load(f, config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 698, in load
    self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core, filename=filename, argv=argv, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 670, in _load_launch
    self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context, None, is_core, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 634, in _recurse_load
    val = self._include_tag(tag, context, ros_config, default_machine, is_core, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 95, in call
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 553, in _include_tag
    inc_filename = self.resolve_args(tag.attributes['file'].value, context)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 159, in resolve_args
    return substitution_args.resolve_args(args, context=context.resolve_dict, resolve_anon=self.resolve_anon)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 299, in resolve_args
    resolved = _resolve_args(resolved, context, resolve_anon, commands)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 312, in _resolve_args
    resolved = commands[command](resolved, a, args, context)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 137, in _find
    return _find_executable(resolve_without_path, a, [args[0], path], context)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 173, in _find_executable
    full_path = _get_executable_path(rp.get_path(args[0]), path)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 190, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
ResourceNotFound: [vp6242_config]
```

Does ResourceNotFound  mean any other error?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188633/resourcenotfound-when-launching-%5Brobot%5D_moveit_config-launch_file/) by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2014-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> However, when I run
>
> roslaunch moveit_planning_execution.launch

Is this an actual copy/paste of the command you run? What happens when you execute:

```
roslaunch vp6242_config moveit_planning_execution.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0